# Sometimes my MacBook Pro wont boot at all

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, kernel-panic

I have a 2015 15" MacBook Pro with specs below
[image]
Lately my Mac wont wakeup from sleep and I have to force shutdown it. When I turn on back my Mac it won't boot (Keyboard and Screen didn't turn on at all but my external keyboard got power). After hard pressing power button several times my Mac booted up and this message appears

```
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff801422c071): AppleAHCIDiskQueueManager::setPowerState(0xffffff9031fc7240 : 0xffffff801617fcf0, 0 -> 3) timed out after 101927 ms @IOServicePM.cpp:5524
Panicked task 0xffffff94fe3e9670: 204 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Backtrace (CPU 4), panicked thread: 0xffffff8b6514f550, Frame : Return Address
0xffffffd04c453a30 : 0xffffff8013a83e1d 
0xffffffd04c453a80 : 0xffffff8013be3ca6 
0xffffffd04c453ac0 : 0xffffff8013bd34fd 
0xffffffd04c453b10 : 0xffffff8013a23a60 
0xffffffd04c453b30 : 0xffffff8013a841ed 
0xffffffd04c453c50 : 0xffffff8013a839a6 
0xffffffd04c453cb0 : 0xffffff80143164af 
0xffffffd04c453da0 : 0xffffff801422c071 
0xffffffd04c453e00 : 0xffffff801422b839 
0xffffffd04c453e10 : 0xffffff8014245b9e 
0xffffffd04c453e50 : 0xffffff801422a658 
0xffffffd04c453e70 : 0xffffff8013ad71e5 
0xffffffd04c453ee0 : 0xffffff8013ad82b2 
0xffffffd04c453fa0 : 0xffffff8013a2318e 

Process name corresponding to current thread (0xffffff8b6514f550): kernel_task

Mac OS version:
21E230

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 21.4.0: Mon Feb 21 20:34:37 PST 2022; root:xnu-8020.101.4~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 9619904E-EA6D-3D08-89C4-B1C0451D39B8
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000013800000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff8013a00000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000013810000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff8013a10000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8013900000
System model name: MacBookPro11,5 (Mac-06F11F11946D27C5)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 482443065550
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x0000007053d908ea
  Sleep   : 0x00000057589ec73f 0x000000006ba2c428 0x0000004bbf7e27a6
  Wake    : 0x0000005768f58303 0x0000000072596100 0x000000576029b767
Compressor Info: 0% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 0% of segments limit (OK) with 0 swapfiles and OK swap space
Zone info:
  Foreign : 0xffffff80190d9000 - 0xffffff80190e7000
  Native  : 0xffffff803165f000 - 0xffffffa03165f000
  Readonly: 0xffffff84fe32b000 - 0xffffff8697cc4000
  Metadata: 0xffffffd53d442000 - 0xffffffd55d5c8000
  Bitmaps : 0xffffffd55d5c8000 - 0xffffffd5635c8000

last started kext at 20829295909: >driverkit.serial 6.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7faccb7000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>AGPM   127
@kext.AMDFramebuffer    4.0.8
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!AHDAHardwareConfigDriver  340.2
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.9
>!AHDA  340.2
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   4.0.8
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000    4.0.8
>AGDCBacklightControl   6.5.4
>!ACameraInterface  7.9.1
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 6.5.4
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   6.5.4
>!A!IHD5000Graphics 18.0.5
>pmtelemetry    1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>usb.!UUserHCI  1
>!AHV   1
>!ADiskImages2  126.100.13
>!ASMCLMU   212
>eficheck   1
>!AFIVRDriver   4.1.0
>!AMuxControl   6.5.4
>!ALPC  3.1
>!ABacklight    180.5
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!A!IFramebufferAzul    18.0.5
>!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
>ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
@kext.AMD7000!C 4.0.8
@UVCService 1
>!AMCCSControl  1.15
|SCSITaskUserClient 456.100.7
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    5440.11
>!UTopCaseDriver    5440.11
>!UCardReader   533.100.11
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
>!AAHCIPort 351.100.4
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.lifs   1
@filesystems.apfs   1934.101.3
@filesystems.hfs.kext   583.100.10
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ARTC  2.0.1
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    402
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
@kec.!AEncryptedArchive 1
>driverkit.serial   6.0.0
|IOSerial!F 11
@kext.triggers  1.0
>DspFuncLib 340.2
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
@kext.AMDRadeonX4030HWLibs  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices  4.0.8
>!UAudio    415.11
>!AAudioClockLibs   140.1
>!AHDA!C    340.2
|IOHDA!F    340.2
|IOAudio!F  340.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IO!BSerialManager  9.0.0
|IO!BPacketLogger   9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CTransport    9.0.0
>IO!BHost!CPCIeTransport    9.0.0
|IOAVB!F    1040.6
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    1040.3
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
|CSR!BHost!CUSBTransport    9.0.0
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   9.0.0
|Broadcom!B20703USBTransport    9.0.0
>!AIPAppender   1.0
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
>!AGraphicsControl  6.5.4
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  594
@!AGPUWrangler  6.5.4
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
|IOAccelerator!F2   462.8
>!AThunderboltEDMSink   5.0.3
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  8.5.1
>IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
@kext.AMDSupport    4.0.8
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    6.5.4
|IOGraphics!F   594
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>!AActuatorDriver   5440.11
>!AHS!BDriver   5440.11
>IO!BHIDDriver  9.0.0
>!AMultitouchDriver 5440.11
>!AInputDeviceSupport   5440.6
>!AHIDKeyboard  228.1
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.5.1
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.5.1
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
>!AXsanScheme   3
|IOAHCIBlock!S  333.100.3
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.81
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.3
|IO80211!FLegacy    1200.12.2b1
|IOSkywalk!F    1.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOAHCI!F   297
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  302.14
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   1040.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 9.0.0
|IOReport!F 47
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  533.100.11
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  210.101.2
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  456.100.7
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  456.100.7
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
$!AImage4   4.2.0
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 12.0
```

I've read the message but still have no idea what caused the problem :/. Any idea why this keeps happening?

Comment: Are you usually on battery power when you're unable to wake the system and have to force shutdown?

Comment: @pion both when using ac power and battery power

Comment: Your Mac may be too old to support SMART but let's check anyway: Can you open **Disk Utility**, go to **View > Show All Devices**, select your physical SSD, and check the **S.M.A.R.T. Status**?

Comment: @pion it says S.M.A.R.T status: verified

Comment: 1. Can you boot into Apple Diagnostics and check your hardware? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731 2. Can you boot into macOS Recovery and run Disk First Aid on your boot drive? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210898

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities: a software problem, or a hardware problem.

First, you need to identify or rule out software problems. Check that all third-party software, particularly things that run Launch Agents or Launch Demons in the background, are compatible and up-to-date.
I recommend EtreCheck as a useful utility that will give you a useful report of things installed on your Mac that may have an effect on normal operation.

You can test whether the problem occurs when in Safe Boot mode.

You can also test whether the problem occurs in a brand new user account: if things work properly, then you know that the cause is something configured or launched in your original user account.

You can also test booting from a clean OS, on an external disk. If that also exhibits the problem, then that would point more towards a hardware problem.